# I want to find $(a \times b^{-1})$ modulo $p$ where $p$ is a prime number?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

By Fermat's little theorem we know that $b^{-1} \bmod p = b^{p-2} \bmod p$ so to compute the above I just need to find $b^{p-2} \bmod p$ and then $(a* b^{p-2} \bmod p)  \bmod p$ should give the answer? My doubt is that as we know multiplication of any two numbers $x$ and $y$: $(xy)\bmod p$ is evaluated as $((x\bmod p)* (y\bmod p))\bmod p$ by properties of modulus. So do we have again take modulus of $b^{p-2} \bmod p$ to calculate the expression $(ab^{-1})\bmod p$ correctly like this $((a \bmod p)((b^{p-2} \bmod p)\bmod p)) \bmod p$ or the correct value of expression $(ab^{-1})\bmod p$ will be $((a \bmod p)*(b^{p-2} \bmod p))\bmod p$ only?

Comment: This is hard to read.  [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a good tutorial on formatting for this site.

Comment: What is the difference between $b^{p-2}\bmod p$ and $(b^{p-2}\bmod p)\bmod p$??

Comment: It doesn't matter if you do extra mod p reductions in between, as long as you do one at the end. In practice, the reason for doing the extra reductions in between is to keep the numbers small and managable. The answer will be the same regardless.

Answer (score 1):

Well, yes, you can multiply in modulus.
If $b^{-1}\mod{p}= b^{p-2}\mod p$ then $a{b^{-1}}\mod{p}= a{b^{p-2}}\mod p$.
Is that your question?